# What is difference between proxy server and anonymizer?

Tags: proxy

Both `proxy server` and `anonymizer` working as a mediator between your ip and target website.

> As per my understanding -> In anonymizer, specially in "Network
>   anonymizer" it pass the request from all the computer connected to
>   same network so it will complex to trace your ip.

Is my above understanding is correct?
What is the main difference or they are same?

Answer (score 2):

I found this [article](http://www.articlebiz.com/article/146648-1-what-is-vpn-anonymizers-proxy-servers-/)

So, while the proxy server is the actual server that passes your information, anonymizer is just the name given to the online service per se. An anonymizer uses underlying proxy servers to be able to give you anonymity.